# UILabel in view 2 Displaying UITextField text in view 1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to enter some text in a `UITextField` in my first view controller, and I want the text I type in to display as label in another collection view controller, much like Google keep or any notes app in general. I am having a very hard time getting the text to display in my second collection view controller cell.

**First view controller header:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ideaText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *enterButton;
```

**Second collection view controller header:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface IDEERViewController : UICollectionViewController
<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *iDEERCollectionView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController *previousViewController;
```

**Collection view controller implementation:**

```
#import "IDEERViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell1.h"

@interface IDEERViewController (){
    NSArray *ideerLabel;

}
@end
@implementation IDEERViewController

@synthesize iDEERCollectionView;
@synthesize previousViewController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.iDEERCollectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.iDEERCollectionView setDataSource:self];

    // Initialize recipe image array
    NSString *textValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",previousViewController.ideaText.text];
    ideerLabel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textValue, nil];
//
//    self.collectionLabel.text = @"hello";

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return ideerLabel.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    CollectionViewCell1 *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell collectionLable]setText:[ideerLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Right now after I run the program and I go to the collection view page, I get `(Null)` instead of whatever I type in the text field in the first controller.

Thank you so much for your help!

*EDIT* 
here is the source for the first controller

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController{

}

@synthesize ideaText;
@synthesize enterButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)onDismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [ideaText resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void) handleBackgroundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [ideaText resignFirstResponder];
}

//press enter and send text to next view.

@end
```

Comment: It is unclear from your source if you are ever setting `previousViewController` or if `previousViewController` is being set before `viewDidLoad` is called.  We would need source from the first view controller.

Comment: Thank you Brian, here is the source for the first view controller

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes, there are two view controllers in storyboard, all the textfields and buttons are connected to .h files. let me upload a screenshot

Comment: I guess I can't i dont have enough rep. :(

Comment: The below answer looks correct to me. You don't have any point where you're setting `previousViewController` and this shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure how you are pushing your view controllers, but here is how you capture the value from one view controller to other.

If you are using storyboard, you can use `prepareForSegue:sender:` in view controller 1:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString @"some string"])
    {
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewcontroller];
        [[vc label] setText:@"SomeText"];
    }
}
```

If you are not using storyboards, you can invoke your method before presenting or pushing your second view controller:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"somexib" bundle:nil];
    [[vc label] setText:@"sometext"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:yes];
}
```

This should give you the idea of how to pass the value from one controller to other using storyboards and using regular view controller push.

Comment: This looks good to me, but I would swap out `[[vc label] setText:@"sometext"]` with the relevant `vc.previousViewController = self`